# How to create a right select query from 3 tables (SUM)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:

```
+-----+---------+
|cl_id|  name   |
+-----+---------+
|   1 |   adaf  |
|   2 |   rich  | - clients
|   3 |   call  |
|   4 |   alen  |
|   5 | courney |
|   6 |  warren |
+-----+---------+

+-----+---------+
|cl_id|  data   |
+-----+---------+
|   1 |      13 |
|   2 |    1000 | - table1
|   5 |      0  |
|   6 |      0  |
+-----+---------+

+-----+---------+
|cl_id|  data   |
+-----+---------+
|   2 |    -355 | - table2
|   3 |  35     | 
|   3 |  10     | 
|   5 |     46  |
|   5 |     50  |
|   5 |     10  |
+-----+---------+
```

And I have to combine those three tables, so the result should be:

```
+-----+---------+--------+---------+
|cl_id| name    |data_tb1|data_tb2 |
+-----+---------+--------+---------+
|   1 |   adaf  |    13  |      0  |
|   2 |   rich  |   1000 |    -355 |
|   3 |   call  |     0  |      45 |
|   4 |   alen  |     0  |      0  |
|   5 |  courney|     0  |     106 |
|   6 |  warren |     0  |      0  |
+-----+---------+--------+---------+
```

It should output all clients and theirs `SUM(data)` from table1 and table2. clients goes one-to-more.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done

Comment: This looks like a basic SUM and left joins to me.

Comment: @SeanLange I tried, but it outputs not all clients somehow :(

Answer (score 4):

Simply using `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT c.cl_id,
       c.name,
       COALESCE(SUM(t1.data), 0) AS data_tb1,
       COALESCE(SUM(t2.data), 0) AS data_tb2
FROM clients c
     LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON c.cl_id = t1.cl_id
     LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON c.cl_id = t2.cl_id
GROUP BY c.cl_id,
         c.name
ORDER BY c.cl_id;
```

Comment: Why u r using `COALESCE` ? Can't I just simply use `(SUM()) as smth`?

Comment: @ex1t3 because the `SUM` of `NULL`s return `NULL`, so it replaces `NULL` by 0 as you suggested in desired output.

Comment: Sorry, but I forget to put `sql-server` into the tags, if i'm right it's a mysql code, which won't be correctly working in `sql-server` code

Comment: @ex1t3 it's `Sql server` compatible

Comment: well, i'm doing smth wrong `MSSQL Server error.
Incorrect syntax near 'cl'.` `FROM clients c` in my code is `FROM clients cl`

Comment: If you have time and desire to help me, I can show you my own code of this query

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SQL Server` then simple Use `Left Join` as below :

```
SELECT C.cl_id,
       C.name,
       SUM(ISNULL(T.data, 0)) data_tb1,
       SUM(ISNULL(T1.data, 0)) data_tb2
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM clients
) C
LEFT JOIN table1 T ON T.cl_id = C.cl_id
LEFT JOIN table2 T1 ON T1.cl_id = C.cl_id
GROUP BY C.cl_id,
         C.name
ORDER BY C.cl_id;
```

**Desired Output :**

```
+-----+---------+--------+---------+
|cl_id| name    |data_tb1|data_tb2 |
+-----+---------+--------+---------+
|   1 |   adaf  |    13  |      0  |
|   2 |   rich  |   1000 |    -355 |
|   3 |   call  |     0  |      45 |
|   4 |   alen  |     0  |      0  |
|   5 |  courney|     0  |     106 |
|   6 |  warren |     0  |      0  |
+-----+---------+--------+---------+
```